# OracleDataReader. Error: Invalid operation. The connection is closed

Tags: c#, datareader

I encountered error when get something from Oracle DB.

Here is my code:

```
public virtual IDataReader LoadDataReaderWithSqlString(string strQuery, ISessionScope session)
    {
        var s = GetSession(session);
        using (var connection = s.Connection)
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
                connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = s.CreateSQLQuery(strQuery).ToString();
            s.Transaction.Enlist(command); // Set the command to exeute using the NHibernate's transaction
            using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(dataReader.Read())
                    return dataReader;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I debugging, I was able to see the return value in dataReader.
I using NHibernate to Run Raw SQL. I want to return DataReader. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 3):

Are you are trying to return opened `IDataReader`? The problem is that you wrap your `ExecuteReader` in [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) statement. `using` means that your `dataReader` will be disposed after code inside of `using` is executed. So you return disposed object. The solution is: remove `using`:

```
var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
if(dataReader.Read())
    return dataReader;
```

And same for connection object.

**ADD**

As David mentioned in comments you might want to avoid resources leak (I mean the case when connection was opened, but command was not executed), then you should handle exceptions like this:

```
public virtual IDataReader LoadDataReaderWithSqlString(string strQuery, ISessionScope session)
{
    try 
    {
        var s = GetSession(session);
        var connection = s.Connection;

        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            connection.Open();

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = s.CreateSQLQuery(strQuery).ToString();
        s.Transaction.Enlist(command); // Set the command to exeute using the NHibernate's transaction

        try
        {
            var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if(dataReader.Read())
                return dataReader;
        }
        catch (DbException)
        { 
            // error executing command
            connection.Close();
            return null; // or throw; // it depends on your logic
        }
    }
    catch (DbException)
    {
        // if connection was not opened
        return null; // or throw; // it depends on your logic
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Maybe wrap everything in a try catch?

Comment: @DavidMerinos Yes, that could be an option. Thanks!

Comment: Also the second line in this is probably redundant:
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

Comment: hmmm. I still get Error. Invalid operation. The OracleDataReader is closed.

Comment: @kingjia Ok, I need more details: why don't you create a new `DbConnection` instead of using some existing? This could bring you problems.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you having

`using (var connection = s.Connection)` and `using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())`

`using` block will dispose the object ( here `connection` and `dataReader`)

remove the using block if you need to return the `dataReader`